# Access of json object variable returned from MongoDB query fails

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm trying to create a variable from an aggregate query in MongoDB and then use it to make another query.

```
var test_var = db.d_snapshot4.aggregate([{$group : {_id: null, 
                                                    max_snapshot_date: {$max:"$snapshot_date"}, 
                                                    max_snapshot_date_str: 
                                                                        {$max:"$snapshot_date_str"}
                                                    }
                                          }
]);
```

The content of test_var  is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": null,
    "max_snapshot_date": ISODate("2020-05-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "max_snapshot_date_str": "20200531"
}
```

But when I try to see the result of test_var.max_snapshot_date I get nothing back.
I need to use the variable as follows:

```
db.d_snapshot4.aggregate([{$match: {"snapshot_date": {$gte: test_var.max_snapshot_date } }}]);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Dina

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with test_var["max_snapshot_date"]? Or do you get any error?

Comment: When i run it I get the following:                                             
test_var["max_snapshot_date"]
> OK
> Time: 0.001s

Comment: And then from the query that i use i get an error:  [Error] cannot compare to undefined

Comment: So if you print the variable test_var you see the content you showed in your question. What happens if you print the  test_var["max_snapshot_date"] ? Do you see : ISODate("2020-05-31T00:00:00.000Z") ?